# How can I disable AMD radeon and use Intel Integrated Graphics on 2011 iMac?

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I have a mid 2011 iMac, 27-inch. The graphics card has failed, and causes the computer to randomly crash. This is a known issue, but it didn't fail in time for Apple's replacement program. But I digress...

I'd like to install Ubuntu on it and disable the broken AMD graphics card so I can use the integrated Intel graphics. The output of

```
lspci | grep -E 'VGA|Display'
```

is as follows

```
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Blackcomb [Radeon HD 6970M/6990M]
```

Running `lspci -k` shows that the AMD device is using the 'radeon' module, and the Intel device is using 'i915'. So, I'm assuming that this means both graphics devices are detected and have kernel drivers. (If I'm wrong, please let me know)

So, I tried blacklisting 'radeon' in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`, but this causes the system to hang at boot. It gets part of the way through the ubuntu logo loading screen, then the screen spits out some text, ending with the line "Started GNOME display manager." (sorry, I can't get a screenshot of the screen).

How should I proceed, or how should I go about disabling the dedicated graphics card and using the integrated intel graphics?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Gnome shell extension to select the used graphics device from System76. The extension can be used with other desktops than Gnome as well (only from the terminal). This extention us usually used to save power, but it might be useful for your problem as well.

[System76 gnome shell extension installation guide](https://support.system76.com/articles/graphics-switch-ubuntu/)

This is not a very clean solution but might solve your problem after blacklisting was not successful.